# Help me prove the following probldem regarding continuity of functions.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Let $f:(a,b) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function. Let $x_1,x_2,x_3,\dots,x_n \in (a,b)$. Prove that there exists a point $c \in (a,b)$ such that 
$$f(c) = \dfrac{f(x_1)+f(x_2)+......+f(x_n)}{n}
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n \in (a,b)$, there is a closed interval $[a',b'] \subset (a,b)$ which contains all of them.

Let
$$
\alpha = \frac{f(x_1) + f(x_2) + \ldots + f(x_n)}{n}
$$
and write
$$
M = \max\{f(x) : x\in [a',b']\}, \text{ and } m = \min\{f(x) : x\in [a',b']\}
$$
Then
$$
m \leq \alpha \leq M
$$
and hence by the Intermediate Value Theorem, there exists a $c \in [a',b']$ such that
$$
f(c) = \alpha
$$

Comment: The function $f$ is defined on $(a,b)$, rather than $[a,b]$; your argument can be easily adjusted, though.

Comment: @egreg : Thanks for pointing that out. Argument fixed :)

Comment: The intermediate value theorem requires that the function is continuous at the interval specified. How do we prove that the function is continuous at $[a',b']$ ?

Comment: Its continuous on $(a,b)$ which contains $[a',b']$

Comment: How do we prove that $m\leq \alpha \leq M$?